# Correct python code to insert NULL value into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, null

I'm attempting to insert some variables into a MySQL database using python. Sometimes the variables will be strings and sometimes they will be None.

A hugely simplified version of what I am attempting is below:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
f = "Bob"
m = None
l = "Smith"

db = mdb.connect("blah blah blah")
with db:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO name (first, middle, last) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')".format(f, m, l))
```

The problem is that it inserts 'None' as a string rather than as an actual NULL value.

I can solve the problem by changing the last line to:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO name (first, middle, last) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (f, m, l))
```

but I believe that this leaves the code vulnerable to MySQL injection attacks.
If anyone knows the correct way using the .format method I would be very grateful.

Comment: No, the string formatting leaves you vulnerable. Passing values the second way is what is expected.

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad I got my apology for the dumb question in early

Comment: Its not a dumb question. Its important you know how to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected method of inserting data is the following:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO name (first, middle, last) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (f, m, l))
```

Formatting a string like in your first example leaves your application vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Exactly. Neither deprecated `%`, nor `.format` will not work in this case.